# Error converting replicasisland from SVN in Eclipse to an Android Project

Tags: android

I have been trying this for hours without success.

http://replicaisland.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

I have added the repository and successfully downloaded the project into the workspace using the option "check out as a project in the workspace" calling it replicaisland.  I tired using the option "check out as project using the New Configuration Wizard" but when I selected and android project I had to enter details that I don't yet have.

I right click on the project and select "convert to Android project" which gives me an error

```
Errors occurred during the build.
  Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'replicaisland'.
  Path must include project and resource name: /replicaisland
  Path must include project and resource name: /replicaisland
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution::

Open the  .project file inside your project folder

add
1) inside `<buildSpec>` add `<name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>`

```
  <buildSpec>
     ...
     ...
     ...
  <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
```

2) inside `<natures>` add `<nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>`

```
<natures>
            ...
           <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
```

3)go to Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source -> add folder replicaisland/gen

Comment: Great, this helped me finally get a project imported! You couldn't by any chance explain what has gone wrong when we need to hack it together like this?

Comment: same problem, I have those in my project file and still the error. If I had an idea what system was having a problem. It has something to do with the android build process, because if I do an eclipse clean the error goes away until I try and run when all the generated stuff is generated...

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to just create a new dummy Android project. Then go to that project folder and copy the `.classpath` and `.project` files to your checked out project folder.

Then in the `.project` change the `<name>` element to your project name.